# The cost of saving the query result to a table in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

As title stated.
I'm curious about there's a python AIP (QueryJobConfig) that I can set the destination table where I can save the query result, so for this kind of saving how much will it cost in GCP?

There are two types of way that I can load or insert external data to BigQuery. (Streaming and Batch uploading)
However, using streaming insert might be costly.

To make it clear, saving the query result may consider as an insertion, so if I use this method to update a table frequently, will it be costly as doing the streaming insert.

Comment: Hi mate. I don't think your question is clear at all but I have a few ideas on what you might be asking this for. Can you rewrite some of this to make it clear (1) What do you have (2) What do you want to have (3) What are your constrains in order of priority. 
I am happy to help then.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the unclear statement. What I mean is how much will it cost for the action of writing (saving) the query result to a table, just the action. I know I will have to pay for the storage in BigQuery. However, I'm curious about the action of writing the result to the table. Thank you so much.

Comment: @LIN Ryan while running a query and writing results to the table you are paying for: query price and storage price (no action/streaming costs). You can estimate query cost [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/estimate-costs). You can refer to my answer as well.

Comment: @muscat Thanks for the clear information. I think it solves my question. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BigQuery [saves query results](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/writing-results) to a table, which can be either permanent or temporary.

**Temporary table** has a lifetime of 24 hours and you are not charged for storing temporary tables.

When you write query results to a **permanent table**, you can create/append/overwrite the table. When you specify a destination table for large query results, you are charged for storing the data. Storage pricing is based on the amount of data stored in your tables. Please, refer to official documentation describing [BigQuery pricing](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#storage).

[Streaming insert](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery) can be done either using DataFlow jobs or by calling the BigQuery streaming insert API directly. You need to pay for streaming insert process ($0.01per 200 MB) and storage of the new data.

If you wish to estimate storage and query cost, please refer to [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/estimate-costs).

I hope you find the above pieces of information useful.